# Updating one field with the same value based on the ID of another field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

The table I'm working with has the following type of data:

| Emp_ID | Name | State |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1112 | joe | CA |
| 1112 | bob | Null |
| 1112 | lisa | Null |

What I'd like to do is have it so that wherever one of the records has a value in the 'State' field such as 'CA' as in the above table, and other records with that same Emp_ID are Null, they'd get replaced with the 'CA' value so it would look like this:

| Emp_ID | Name | State |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1112 | joe | CA |
| 1112 | bob | CA |
| 1112 | lisa | CA |

so IF Emp_ID has a value that IS NOT NULL in the State field
THEN State value in the State field if the Emp_ID is the same as that which has the state value.

Most of my research pointed me to DML commands such as updating the problem set but I don't have permission to change table data without addressing the specifics of the problem I'm trying to solve.

Looking for direction on how I could potentially solve for this problem.

Comment: @DaleK I know it's SO etiquette to show one's own attempts but I genuinely haven't gotten nowhere near the result I'm looking for. My attempts either ended in errors or simply didn't mount to anything that would aid anyone that is looking to assist with this post. I'm not necessarily looking for answers, direction will do just as well. I've made sure to state this on the main post

Comment: Unfortunately thats just not the way this site works - its intended to help solve specific technical issues encountered, not give more general advice. That said, you have an answer below which you haven't responded to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head, using an updatable CTE:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, MAX(State) OVER (PARTITION BY Emp_ID) AS MaxState
    FROM yourTable
)

UPDATE cte
SET State = MaxState
WHERE State IS NULL;
```